# Returning HashMap values and keys through an array method

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to return keys and values through an array method.

I have done this:

```
public ArrayList<String> translationList() {
    for (String key : translations.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " = ");
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(this.translations.values());
}
```

And in my Main.java

```
ArrayList<String> translations = dictionary.translationList();
for (String translation : translations) {
    System.out.println(translation);
}
```

It returns

```
apina = 
cembalo = 
banaani = 
monkey
harpsichord
banana
```

I'm not sure how to get them to print on the same line after the translation of the word. I know it's printing the for loop before returning the array but that is where my problem is and not sure how to solve it.

Comment: use `System.out.println("translations="+translations);` or inside `for-loop` use `System.out.print(translation);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting only values back there is no way to get key based on value. So hence not possible.

What you can do is return keys from method and iterate that in your method.

or simply change your method to

```
public ArrayList<String> translationList() {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>(String);
    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {

                returnList.add(entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue());

        }
    return returnList;
}
```

and in your main method

```
ArrayList<String> translations = dictionary.translationList();
for (String translation : translations) {
    System.out.println(translation);
}
```

Comment: I understand but I'm not sure how I could do that, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Okay I see, the website I'm doing exercises on hasn't taught me about getKey or getValue so I didn't know to use them. Would there be no other way to do this? Thank you for your help

Comment: @syntax This is the way I know.